# How to use numeric indices in cross-validation with pd.DataFrame in scikit-learn (disable _safe_split)?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to disable the `safe_indexing` and force the indicies that I've given my model.

I can't simply do `X.values` and `y.values` because I have a custom classifier that I've made where the column/attribute labels used during the `__init__` (crucial for the algorithm).

This is from the following line of code:

```
model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X=X, y=y, cv=cv, n_jobs=1, scoring="accuracy")
```

where `cv` is a list of lists with numeric indices

**`X` has to be a `pd.DataFrame` and `cv` has to be predefined indicies.  How I can make this work?**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-e1775ca32abb> in <module>()
      1 smc.fit(X,y)
----> 2 smc.cross_validate(X,y,cv=cv, n_jobs=1)

<ipython-input-72-61f814fd075c> in cross_validate(self, X, y, cv, scoring, n_jobs, **args)
    150                     cv_idx.append((idx_tr.map(lambda x:X.index.get_loc(x)), idx_te.map(lambda x:X.index.get_loc(x))))
    151                 cv = cv_idx
--> 152         return model_selection.cross_val_score(self, X=X, y=y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, scoring=scoring, **args)

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
    340                                 n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose,
    341                                 fit_params=fit_params,
--> 342                                 pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
    343     return cv_results['test_score']
    344 

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score)
    204             fit_params, return_train_score=return_train_score,
    205             return_times=True)
--> 206         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
    207 
    208     if return_train_score:

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    623                 return False
    624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    626                 return True
    627 

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    446     start_time = time.time()
    447 
--> 448     X_train, y_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, train)
    449     X_test, y_test = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, test, train)
    450 

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/metaestimators.py in _safe_split(estimator, X, y, indices, train_indices)
    198             X_subset = X[np.ix_(indices, train_indices)]
    199     else:
--> 200         X_subset = safe_indexing(X, indices)
    201 
    202     if y is not None:

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in safe_indexing(X, indices)
    144     if hasattr(X, "iloc"):
    145         # Work-around for indexing with read-only indices in pandas
--> 146         indices = indices if indices.flags.writeable else indices.copy()
    147         # Pandas Dataframes and Series
    148         try:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'flags'
```

In response to the suggestions in the comments (2018-June-04):
[image]

Comment: Cross_val_score only does split the data and fits the data on train and scores on test with some parallelization. But since you are using n_jobs=1, you can easily duplicate the behaviour by iteration a StratifiedKFold (for classification) or KFold (for regression) and do the training and test yourself.

Comment: I only did `n_jobs = 1` because the error message is cleaner.  I have it set up right now with manual `cv` but the `model_selection.cross_val_score` is just too good to not use :)

Comment: In that case, you can use [`PredefinedSplit()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.PredefinedSplit.html) as your cv which accepts user defined splits.

Comment: Will that work if my indices are numeric and my data is pandas?

Comment: Yes it should. Splitting in itself doesnt change the data type.